# Responsive button thumbnail height and width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create css which will work for responsive button like bootstrap "img-thumbnail". That means, whatever I change the screen size, button's height and width will change accordingly.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you looked into bootstrap media queries: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries ???

Comment: Can you show us one of you attempts?
Is the button an image, text or text with icon?
If it is text, do you want to make the text larger as well?

Comment: I want to make 3 rows and 4 columns. Inside this cell evry same size of button will be there(rectangular button). As per resolution size of the button will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit messy, but are you looking for something like this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button-panel">
    <div class="row button-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 1">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 2">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 3">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 4">  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row button-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 5">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 6">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 7">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 8">  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row button-row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 9">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 10">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 11">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 button-container">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Button 12">  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button-panel {
    height: 100vh;
}
.button-row {
    height: calc(100% / 3);
}
.button-container {
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.btn-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eJBZ9PwLmE)